# How Pseudorandom number generator gets "first" seed number?

Tags: c#, .net

I tried to understand better random number generating process, in particular pseudorandom number generation in .NET (actually MONO), and I am after reading these articles: [MSDN Random](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [wikipedia Random number generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation).

So I think I get it (.NET uses modified version of Donald E. Knuth's subtractive random number generator algorithm).

The only thing that stays unclear to me is how this algorithm gets its first seed number. I tried to find info, but didn't.

Does it takes from pseudorandom number generator too? It doesnt make sense, does it? First seed needs to be somehow random too, couse if not first random number in every instance of .NET application would be the same. If so, quessing next results from applications like games would be quite easy (if the author of application didn't modify the number after generation). So I am quessing the first seed number, I mean first input to the generator must be taken from something unique for machine or current application process, but I am just quessing.

**So my question is: If my thinking process is correct (if not please correct me), how generator gets its first input for given algorithm?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The default seed value is derived from the system clock

source [Random() constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9(v=vs.110).aspx)

So separate instances get different random values. However if you create multiple instances of this class quickly, they may end up using the same clock-tick as seed - and thus generate the same sequence.

Comment: Many thanks, there are other correct answers so I accept the latest one.

Comment: Why last? First I think

Answer (score 4):

From the [`Reference Random Class`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,bb77e610694e64ca)

```
public Random() 
: this(Environment.TickCount) {
}

public Random(int Seed) {
        ///....
}
```

It's calculated based on your input or the Tick count

Comment: @MichaelMairegger could you explain me (a bit more than in the edit reason) why you removed the inner code from my post please :) ?

Comment: I removed the code because the constructor listing already provides the anwer the questioner was looking for.

Comment: Many thanks, there are other correct answers so I accept the latest one.

Answer (score 3):

The `Random` class has a constructor that takes either no or one parameter of type `int`. Thus you can set the initial seed by your own.
If you do not provide a parameter than as the documentations says a time-dependent value is used as seed. The default values is the number of ticks ([see source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,53)) that have elapsed since the system started up.

Comment: Many thanks, there are other correct answers so I accept the latest one.

Answer (score 2):

`System.Random` uses `Environment.TickCount` as the seed in its parameterless constructor, as per [.NET source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs).

Comment: Many thanks, there are other correct answers so I accept the latest one.